# Use mutate inside a function called by an apply family function

Tags: r

I am trying to change some of my data that are stored as tibbles inside a list.
This list of tibbles was generated by a package.

I do not understand why my function does not work.
If I extract a tibble element manually, the function works but not inside a lapply.

my function:

```
changesomethingtaxize <- function(x, whatchange=NULL, applyfunction=NULL){
library(lazyeval) ;
mutate_call <- lazyeval::interp(~ a(b), a = match.fun(applyfunction), b = as.name(whatchange) )
x %<>% mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(mutate_call), whatchange) ) 
return(x)
}
```

I want to do

```
mydata <- lapply(mydata, function(x) changesomethingtaxize(x, whatchange=rank, applyfunction=str_to_sentence) )
```

I could use a loop to extract each tibbles (in this case I only have 5) but I would like to understand what I do wrong :)

---

From dput()

```js
    mydata <- structure(list(`Zostera marina` = structure(list(name = c("Plantae", 
                                                                    "Viridiplantae", "Streptophyta", "Embryophyta", "Tracheophyta", 
                                                                    "Spermatophytina", "Magnoliopsida", "Lilianae", "Alismatales", 
                                                                    "Zosteraceae", "Zostera", "Zostera marina"), rank = c("kingdom", 
                                                                                                                          "subkingdom", "infrakingdom", "superdivision", "division", "subdivision", 
                                                                                                                          "class", "superorder", "order", "family", "genus", "species"), 
                                                           id = c("202422", "954898", "846494", "954900", "846496", 
                                                                  "846504", "18063", "846542", "38883", "39069", "39073", "39074"
                                                           )), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame"), `Vascular plants` = structure(list(
                                                               name = c("Plantae", "Viridiplantae", "Streptophyta", "Embryophyta", 
                                                                        "Tracheophyta"), rank = c("kingdom", "subkingdom", "infrakingdom", 
                                                                                                  "superdivision", "division"), id = c("202422", "954898", 
                                                                                                                                       "846494", "954900", "846496")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame"), 
                         `Fucus vesiculosus` = structure(list(name = c("Chromista", 
                                                                       "Chromista", "Phaeophyta", "Phaeophyceae", "Fucales", "Fucaceae", 
                                                                       "Fucus", "Fucus vesiculosus"), rank = c("kingdom", "subkingdom", 
                                                                                                               "division", "class", "order", "family", "genus", "species"
                                                                       ), id = c("630578", "590735", "660055", "10686", "11328", 
                                                                                 "11329", "11334", "11335")), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame"), 
                         Macroalgae = NA, `Filamentous algae` = NA), class = "classification", db = "itis")
```

Comment: Corrections:

changesomethingtaxize <- function(x, whatchange=NULL, applyfunction=NULL){
  require(lazyeval) ;
  mutate_call <- lazyeval::interp(~ a(b), a = match.fun(applyfunction), b = as.name(whatchange) )
  
if(!all(is.na(x)) ){
x %<>% mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(mutate_call), whatchange) ) 
}
  return(x)
}

Answer (score 0):

I think I actually found why... :D
The lapply works but was not returning anything because of the NAs (empty elements of the list).

I added an if() that only mutates a tibble if the tibble actually contains something.

It is always an NA issue somewhere!
Well hope that piece of code could help someone someday.

Comment: Naturally this only popped up _after_ I submitted a response. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

The functions you provided aren't usable by themselves, but it looks like you're attempting to use a function meant to modify a data frame on non-dataframe objects, which `mydata` contains.

I'm using `dplyr::mutate()` just to illustrate here.

Your data contain `NA`s (which in this case are `logical`). `dplyr::mutate()` doesnt' have a method for `logical`s and I'm assuming the function you're trying to use doesn't either (or simply doesn't have a way of handling `NA` values).

You should be getting an error that's at least conceptually similar to the following ...

```r
lapply(mydata, function(x) dplyr::mutate(x, col_to_modify = toupper(rank)))
#> Error in UseMethod("mutate_"): no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

To get around this, you can check your list ahead of time and note which elements are indeed data frames.

```r
df_indices <- vapply(mydata, is.data.frame, logical(1L))
df_indices
#>    Zostera marina   Vascular plants Fucus vesiculosus        Macroalgae 
#>              TRUE              TRUE              TRUE             FALSE 
#> Filamentous algae 
#>             FALSE
```

Using `df_indices`, we can modify only those elements in `mydata` like so...

```r
mydata[df_indices] <- lapply(
  mydata[df_indices],
  function(x) dplyr::mutate(x, col_to_modify = toupper(rank))
)
mydata  
#> $`Zostera marina`
#>               name          rank     id col_to_modify
#> 1          Plantae       kingdom 202422       KINGDOM
#> 2    Viridiplantae    subkingdom 954898    SUBKINGDOM
#> 3     Streptophyta  infrakingdom 846494  INFRAKINGDOM
#> 4      Embryophyta superdivision 954900 SUPERDIVISION
#> 5     Tracheophyta      division 846496      DIVISION
#> 6  Spermatophytina   subdivision 846504   SUBDIVISION
#> 7    Magnoliopsida         class  18063         CLASS
#> 8         Lilianae    superorder 846542    SUPERORDER
#> 9      Alismatales         order  38883         ORDER
#> 10     Zosteraceae        family  39069        FAMILY
#> 11         Zostera         genus  39073         GENUS
#> 12  Zostera marina       species  39074       SPECIES
#> 
#> $`Vascular plants`
#>            name          rank     id col_to_modify
#> 1       Plantae       kingdom 202422       KINGDOM
#> 2 Viridiplantae    subkingdom 954898    SUBKINGDOM
#> 3  Streptophyta  infrakingdom 846494  INFRAKINGDOM
#> 4   Embryophyta superdivision 954900 SUPERDIVISION
#> 5  Tracheophyta      division 846496      DIVISION
#> 
#> $`Fucus vesiculosus`
#>                name       rank     id col_to_modify
#> 1         Chromista    kingdom 630578       KINGDOM
#> 2         Chromista subkingdom 590735    SUBKINGDOM
#> 3        Phaeophyta   division 660055      DIVISION
#> 4      Phaeophyceae      class  10686         CLASS
#> 5           Fucales      order  11328         ORDER
#> 6          Fucaceae     family  11329        FAMILY
#> 7             Fucus      genus  11334         GENUS
#> 8 Fucus vesiculosus    species  11335       SPECIES
#> 
#> $Macroalgae
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $`Filamentous algae`
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "classification"
#> attr(,"db")
#> [1] "itis"
```

Note that `{purrr}` has a nice `map()` variant designed to handle this very situation. `purrr::map_if()` takes a `.p` (predicate) argument to which you can provide a function that it applies to `.x` and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Only those elements that return `TRUE` are modified by the function you provide to `.f`

```r
purrr::map_if(.x = mydata, .p = is.data.frame, 
              .f = ~ dplyr::mutate(.x, col_to_modify = toupper(rank)))
#> $`Zostera marina`
#>               name          rank     id col_to_modify
#> 1          Plantae       kingdom 202422       KINGDOM
#> 2    Viridiplantae    subkingdom 954898    SUBKINGDOM
#> 3     Streptophyta  infrakingdom 846494  INFRAKINGDOM
#> 4      Embryophyta superdivision 954900 SUPERDIVISION
#> 5     Tracheophyta      division 846496      DIVISION
#> 6  Spermatophytina   subdivision 846504   SUBDIVISION
#> 7    Magnoliopsida         class  18063         CLASS
#> 8         Lilianae    superorder 846542    SUPERORDER
#> 9      Alismatales         order  38883         ORDER
#> 10     Zosteraceae        family  39069        FAMILY
#> 11         Zostera         genus  39073         GENUS
#> 12  Zostera marina       species  39074       SPECIES
#> 
#> $`Vascular plants`
#>            name          rank     id col_to_modify
#> 1       Plantae       kingdom 202422       KINGDOM
#> 2 Viridiplantae    subkingdom 954898    SUBKINGDOM
#> 3  Streptophyta  infrakingdom 846494  INFRAKINGDOM
#> 4   Embryophyta superdivision 954900 SUPERDIVISION
#> 5  Tracheophyta      division 846496      DIVISION
#> 
#> $`Fucus vesiculosus`
#>                name       rank     id col_to_modify
#> 1         Chromista    kingdom 630578       KINGDOM
#> 2         Chromista subkingdom 590735    SUBKINGDOM
#> 3        Phaeophyta   division 660055      DIVISION
#> 4      Phaeophyceae      class  10686         CLASS
#> 5           Fucales      order  11328         ORDER
#> 6          Fucaceae     family  11329        FAMILY
#> 7             Fucus      genus  11334         GENUS
#> 8 Fucus vesiculosus    species  11335       SPECIES
#> 
#> $Macroalgae
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $`Filamentous algae`
#> [1] NA
```